# WPF Prism - How to be able to load up the correct view to an unkown viewmodel from an external assembly?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef, datatemplate

Basically, here's the situation:

I have the following layout:

- `FooAssembly.dll`: `FooUserControl` and `FooViewModel : NotificationObject`
- `BarAssembly.dll`: `BarUserControl` and `BarViewModel : NotificationObject`

Both are imported using Unity or MEF. I create an instance of the FooViewModel and BarViewModel and add them to an `ObservableCollection<NotificationObject>` which is linked to a TabControl in my main application.

Now, I get their fully qualified names instead of the appropriate views. The solution... to use a DataTemplate right? Problem is I don't know ahead of time in my application to expect a FooUserControl/FooViewModel, and even if I did their types are unknown which means I can't compile that app. So how do you inject the correct view when the views/viewmodels are imported using Unity or MEF?

Comment: Shouldn't you then be using interfaces, and simply asking the container to resolve any/all types of the interface?  The template part might be a little trickier...

Answer (score 0):

I created an interface call `IAppResources` with a method called `AddResourceDictionary(ResourceDictionary rd)`. This interface got used in the Modules to load up ResourceDictionaries, and got implemented in the application to take resource dictionaries and add them to the Application's MergedDictionaries

There might be a better way out there, but this worked for me :)

**Common Interface**

```
public interface IAppResources
{
    void AddResourceDictionary(ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary);
}
```

**Module uses Interface to load Resources**

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyModule(IAppResources appResources)
{
    appResources.AddResourceDictionary(new MyModuleResources());
}
```

**Application implements Interface to load Resources**

```
[Export(typeof(IAppResources ))]
public class AppResources: IAppResources 
{
    #region IAppResources Members

    void IAppResources.AddResourceDictionary(ResourceDictionary resource)
    {
        App.Current.MainWindow.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);
    }

    #endregion
}
```